# Recursively fixing image file extensions in Windows 7

Tags: windows, image, batch-file

Hopefully this is a quick and easy question...

I have the same issue as this user: https://superuser.com/questions/812455/recursively-fixing-image-file-extensions-in-linux except I'm using a Windows (7) machine. (Most software ignores the extension like BlamKiwi mentions, but I'm frequently running into issues with Adobe software.)

I'm asking SO instead of SU since I just need some help translating the 'best answer' code into something that works on my machine.

```
for f in *.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG,jpeg,JPEG}; do 
    type=$( file "$f" | grep -oP '\w+(?= image data)' )
    case $type in  
        PNG)  newext=png ;; 
        JPEG) newext=jpg ;; 
        *)    echo "??? what is this: $f"; continue ;; 
    esac
    ext=${f##*.}   # remove everything up to and including the last dot
    if [[ $ext != $newext ]]; then
        # remove "echo" if you're satisfied it's working
        echo mv "$f" "${f%.*}.$newext"
    fi
done
```

I'm guessing a .batch file can accomplish this but don't know enough to write it myself.

Comment: How far have you got in translating it?

Comment: A few google searches into the basics of batch syntax. I've never written a script myself.

Comment: The above isn't batch-file.

Comment: I was referring only to the progress of an equivalent batch file. I can sort of read bash. (but I'm also getting held up understanding syntax of the original script.)

Comment: Hmm... it is translatable except for `file`. The `file` command does not have equivalent for windows. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/272338/what-is-the-equivalent-to-the-linux-file-command-for-windows) and/or [here](https://superuser.com/questions/274734/is-there-a-tool-that-can-determine-the-file-type-from-containing-data). For alternative, I recommend the [TrID tool](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) (wherein you should download both the Win32 ZIP and the "TrIDDefs.TRD" package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IrfanView** is a freeware (for private usage) multimedia viewer which displays on viewing image files by default a message box if an image file has a file extension not suitable for image format prompting the user to rename the file for correcting the file extension. This message prompt can be disabled in configuration, but it is really useful to detect image files with wrong file extension on viewing them.

Images in [Portable Network Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) format always start with the 4 bytes `89 50 4E 47` (hexadecimal) which are displayed in a command prompt window on using [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) (North America) or [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) (Western Europe) as `ëPNG`.

Images in [JPEG File Interchange Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format) start with the 10 bytes `FF D8 FF E0` **s1 s2** `4A 46 49 46`. The last 4 bytes of those 10 bytes are `JFIF`. **s1 s2** are variable as being a length information.

The command **FINDSTR** is designed for searching for strings in text files, but can be used also for searching for strings in binary files. This is used by the batch file below:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "MessageOutput="
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir *.jpg *jpeg *.png /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul') do (

    %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /M /C:PNG "%%I" >nul
    if errorlevel 1 ( set "IsPNG=" ) else set "IsPNG=1"

    %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /M /C:JFIF "%%I" >nul
    if errorlevel 1 ( set "IsJPG=" ) else set "IsJPG=1"

    if defined IsPNG if defined IsJPG (
        set "FirstPNG=1"
        for /F "delims=:" %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N /C:PNG "%%I"') do (
            if defined FirstPNG (
                if "%%J" == "1" ( set "IsJPG=" ) else set "IsPNG="
                set "FirstPNG="
            )
        )
    )

    if defined IsPNG (
        if /I not "%%~xI" == ".png" (
            echo PNG image "%%I" has wrong file extension.
            ren "%%I" "%%~nI.png"
            set "MessageOutput=1"
        )
    ) else if defined IsJPG (
        if /I "%%~xI" == ".png" (
            echo JPG image "%%I" has wrong file extension.
            ren "%%I" "%%~nI.jpg"
            set "MessageOutput=1"
        )
    ) else (
        echo/
        echo ERROR: File "%%I" is neither a JPG nor a PNG file.
        echo/
        set "MessageOutput=1"
    )
)
if defined MessageOutput (
    echo/
    pause
)
endlocal
```

The command **DIR** is executed by command **FOR** in a separate command process in background to get a list of *.jpg, *.jpeg and *.png file names without path of files in current directory on execution of the batch file.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

It is necessary here to use command **DIR** instead of using

```
for %%I in (*.jpg *jpeg *.png) do (
```

because the list output by **DIR**, captured and processed by **FOR** line by line does not change anymore during the loop iterations. This is important here because of perhaps changing the list of file entries in current directory due to a rename operation. By using **FOR** directly it could happen after a file rename that a file is processed twice or another file in directory is skipped because of directory list change during loop iteration.

The code is written to avoid usage of delayed environment variable expansion to work also for files with an exclamation mark. A different solution would be also possible with using a subroutine.

For each file found by **DIR** first a case-sensitive search for `PNG` is executed on the file and environment variable `IsPNG` is deleted on not found in file or is defined with value `1` on file containing `PNG`.

Next a case-sensitive search for `JFIF` is executed on the file and environment variable `IsJPG` is deleted on not found in file or is defined with value `1` on file containing `JFIF`.

Binary data of an image file can contain anywhere in the data by chance also the hexadecimal byte sequence `50 4E 47` or `4A 46 49 46`. The third **IF** command line checks if the file contains both byte sequences. In this rare case **FINDSTR** searching for **PNG** is executed once again with evaluating in which "line" the string is found. If the line number is `1`, then the string `PNG` is definitely at top of the file which is a quite clear indication that the file is a PNG file, otherwise it should be a JPEG file containing by chance also the bytes `50 4E 47`. The worst case handled by the batch code is a PNG image file containing `PNG` in header and in data `PNG` and `JFIF` which requires evaluating only first occurrence of `PNG` found by **FINDSTR**.

An appropriate message is output and file is renamed (without checking for success) if current image file is (most likely) a PNG file, but does not have expected file extension `.png`. For a *.png file being (most likely) a JPEG file a similar message is output and the file rename is executed for changing the file extension.

It is also possible that the file with extension `.png`, `.jpg` or `.jpeg` does neither contain `PNG` nor `JFIF`, for example on being a GIF file. In this case an error message is output as the image format could not be determined by this batch code.

The batch file execution is halted at end in case of any message is output. This means on double clicking the batch file a console window appears and closes if all *.jpg, *.jpeg and *.png file have the right file extension according to image format.

Of course this solution is definitely not perfect. A text file with first line containing `PNG` and second line containing `JFIF` and having the file extension `.jpg` would interpreted as PNG image file although being in real a text file. **IrfanView** is definitely a better choice for really checking if a *.jpg, *.jpeg or *.png file is really a JPEG or PNG image file.

Here is additionally an alternate solution using a subroutine:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "MessageOutput="

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir *.jpg *jpeg *.png /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul') do call :CheckImage "%%I"

if defined MessageOutput (
    echo/
    pause
)
endlocal
goto :EOF


:CheckImage
set "IsJPG=0"
set "IsPNG=0"

%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /M /C:PNG %1 >nul
if not errorlevel 1 set "IsPNG=1"

%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /M /C:JFIF %1 >nul
if not errorlevel 1 set "IsJPG=1"

if %IsPNG% == 1 if %IsJPG% == 1 (
    for /F "delims=:" %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N /C:PNG %1') do (
        if "%%J" == "1" ( set "IsJPG=0" ) else set "IsPNG=0"
        goto CheckExtension
    )
)

:CheckExtension
if %IsPNG% == 1 (
    if /I not "%~x1" == ".png" (
        echo PNG image %1 has wrong file extension.
        ren %1 "%~n1.png"
        set "MessageOutput=1"
    )
    goto :EOF
)

if %IsJPG% == 1 (
    if /I "%~x1" == ".png" (
        echo JPG image %1 has wrong file extension.
        ren %1 "%~n1.jpg"
        set "MessageOutput=1"
    )
    goto :EOF
)

echo/
echo ERROR: File %1 is neither a JPG nor a PNG file.
echo/
set "MessageOutput=1"
goto :EOF
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`